# mule simple web client soap request with wsdl

Tags: web-services, cxf, mule, webservice-client

I would like to make request to web service from mule flow. So far I got WSDL generate classes (wsdl2java), prepared flow (below), and "successfully" send request. Now, problem is, that even thou I have taken base class from generated class and put it in payload it does not generate required soap.

My flow:

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="testingJob" repeatInterval="10810000" repeatCount="0" startDelay="5000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job groupName="g1job" jobGroupName="g1job">
            <quartz:payload>a</quartz:payload>
        </quartz:event-generator-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="Starting quartz for testing purpouses" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <custom-transformer class="com.example.GenerateSimpleRoutePublish" doc:name="Java"/>
    <cxf:simple-client   doc:name="SOAP"  serviceClass="com.example.ws.MyWebService" operation="send">
    </cxf:simple-client>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9094" path="sync-server-web/services/myws" method="POST" connector-ref="http_internal" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

GenerateSimpleRoutePublish just put base object into payload and move on.

Result that is sent as soap request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:send xmlns:ns1="http://somenamespace.si/">
            <ns1:arg0>
                <ns1:MyRequest>
...
```

But it should look like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:send xmlns:ns1="http://somenamespace.si/">
           <ns1:MyRequest>
...
```

Notice that  is not there anymore in desired xml.

Anyone knows how to achieve that? I did googled a lot but just don't find right solution. If more is required then I can provide info.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="MyWebService" targetNamespace="http://ws.example.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://ws.example.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.example.com/"
            version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://ws.example.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="MyRequest" type="tns:MyRequest" />
            <xs:element name="send" type="tns:send" />
            <xs:element name="sendResponse" type="tns:sendResponse" />
            <xs:complexType name="send">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:MyRequest" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="MyRequest">
                <xs:complexContent>
...
```

Transformer class GenerateSimpleRoutePublish.java:

```
@Override
public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
    event.setMessage(transformMessage(event.getMessage(), event.getEncoding()));
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return event;
}

public MuleMessage transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {

    MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();
    /**
     * some filling of testing data that is formatted correctly when soap is sent.
     */

    Send send = new Send();
    send.setMSyequest(myRequest);//the only setter method available for Send

    message.setPayload(send);
    return message;
}
```

Send.java methods and xml definition:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "send", propOrder = {"myRequest"})

public MyRequest getMyRequest()
public void setMyRequest(MyRequest value)
```

Comment: It's very difficult to judge the issue without your XSD/WSDL and your transformer class ... Could you please share them ?

Comment: Ok I added WSDL (shortened version). This part should be enough (it is ~2k lines otherwise but "send" basically just wrap MyRequest which contains more nodes. In generated code I have only setter and getter for MyRequest in Send class, nothing else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom-transformer you could use Groovy script to send SOAP request to webservice client just as Java pojo class... Please check the reference :- https://m-square.com.au/consuming-net-wcf-soap-web-services-from-mule/